# Using Spark CombineByKey with set of values

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have the following dataset:

```
val data = sc.parallelize(Array(
    ("group1","value1"),("group1","value2"),("group1", "value1"),
    ("group2","value1"),("group1","value1"),("group3", "value3")
))
```

I'm using Spark, and I would like to obtain the following result:

```
Array(("group1","value1",3),("group1", "value2",1),("group2","value1",1),("group3","value3",1)
```

I have tried to use `CombineByKey` but my combiner does not work.

I looked at the code described here http://codingjunkie.net/spark-combine-by-key/ but my combiner does not work, as I want to count the number of instances and not the sum of some numbers.

Here is my code:

```
val reduced = data.combineByKey(
(value) => {
  println(s"Create combiner -> ${value}")
  (value, 1)
},
(acc: (Array[String], Int), v) => {
  println(s"""Merge value : (${acc._1} :+ ${v}, ${acc._2} + 1)""")
  (acc._1 :+ v, acc._2 + 1)
},
(acc1: (Array[String], Int), acc2: (Array[String], Int)) => {
  println(s"""Merge Combiner : (${acc1._1} :+ ${acc2._1}, ${acc1._2} + ${acc2._2})""")
  (acc1._1 :+ acc2._1, acc1._2 + acc2._2)
}
)
```

Do you have any advice ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't `combineByKey` here. `reduceByKey` will do just fine:

```
data.map((_, 1))
  .reduceByKey(_ + _)
  .map { case ((k1, k2), v) => (k1, k2, v) }
  .collect

// Array[(String, String, Int)] = Array((group3,value3,1), (group1,value1,3), (group1,value2,1), (group2,value1,1)
```

Your code doesn't work because

```
(value) => {
  println(s"Create combiner -> ${value}")
 (value, 1)
}
```

is of type `String => (String, Int)` and `mergeValue` expects `(Array[String], Int)`. Later you use incorrect method to concatenate `Arrays`.

If changed like this:

```
val reduced = data.combineByKey(
  (value) => {
    (Array(value), 1)
  },
  (acc: (Array[String], Int), v) => {
    (acc._1 :+ v, acc._2 + 1)
  },
  (acc1: (Array[String], Int), acc2: (Array[String], Int)) => {
    (acc1._1 ++ acc2._1, acc1._2 + acc2._2)
  }
)
```

it would compile but result wouldn't be the one you expect:

```
result.collect
// Array[(String, (Array[String], Int))]  = Array((group3,(Array(value3),1)), (group1,(Array(value1, value2, value1, value1),4)), (group2,(Array(value1),1)))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I suspect my first part of the combiner to be wrong, but can't find what is going wrong.